# How to use rkt as container runtime instead of docker for kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, rkt

I tried using rktlet(https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/rktlet/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guide.md)

But when I try to

```
kubelet --cgroup-driver=systemd \
> --container-runtime=remote \
> --container-runtime-endpoint=/var/run/rktlet.sock \
> --image-service-endpoint=/var/run/rktlet.sock
```

I am getting the below errors

```
Flag --cgroup-driver has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
I0320 13:10:21.661373    3116 server.go:407] Version: v1.13.4
I0320 13:10:21.663411    3116 plugins.go:103] No cloud provider specified.
W0320 13:10:21.664635    3116 server.go:552] standalone mode, no API client
W0320 13:10:21.669757    3116 server.go:464] No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server.
I0320 13:10:21.669791    3116 server.go:666] --cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /
I0320 13:10:21.670018    3116 container_manager_linux.go:248] container manager verified user specified cgroup-root exists: []
I0320 13:10:21.670038    3116 container_manager_linux.go:253] Creating Container Manager object based on Node Config: {RuntimeCgroupsName: SystemCgroupsName: KubeletCgroupsName: ContainerRuntime:remote CgroupsPerQOS:true CgroupRoot:/ CgroupDriver:systemd KubeletRootDir:/var/lib/kubelet ProtectKernelDefaults:false NodeAllocatableConfig:{KubeReservedCgroupName: SystemReservedCgroupName: EnforceNodeAllocatable:map[pods:{}] KubeReserved:map[] SystemReserved:map[] HardEvictionThresholds:[{Signal:nodefs.inodesFree Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.05} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:imagefs.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.15} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:memory.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:100Mi Percentage:0} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:nodefs.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.1} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>}]} QOSReserved:map[] ExperimentalCPUManagerPolicy:none ExperimentalCPUManagerReconcilePeriod:10s ExperimentalPodPidsLimit:-1 EnforceCPULimits:true CPUCFSQuotaPeriod:100ms}
I0320 13:10:21.670125    3116 container_manager_linux.go:272] Creating device plugin manager: true
I0320 13:10:21.670151    3116 state_mem.go:36] [cpumanager] initializing new in-memory state store
I0320 13:10:21.670254    3116 state_mem.go:84] [cpumanager] updated default cpuset: ""
I0320 13:10:21.670271    3116 state_mem.go:92] [cpumanager] updated cpuset assignments: "map[]"
W0320 13:10:21.672059    3116 util_unix.go:77] Using "/var/run/rktlet.sock" as endpoint is deprecated, please consider using full url format "unix:///var/run/rktlet.sock".
W0320 13:10:21.672124    3116 util_unix.go:77] Using "/var/run/rktlet.sock" as endpoint is deprecated, please consider using full url format "unix:///var/run/rktlet.sock".
E0320 13:10:21.673168    3116 remote_runtime.go:72] Version from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService
E0320 13:10:21.673228    3116 kuberuntime_manager.go:184] Get runtime version failed: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService
F0320 13:10:21.673249    3116 server.go:261] failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService
```

How do I create a kube cluster using rkt? Please help.

Comment: Where are you deploying this cluster? Which tool are using to launch the cluster? usually you specify the runtime on cluster launch

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do it in a aws t2medium instance.

Answer (score 2):

That's the way to run `Rktlet`. However, Rktlet is still pretty experimental and I believe it's not being actively developed either. The [last commit](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/rktlet/commit/fd7fc6bf4a25f03c22e5f6e30f3d9f12c468afcb) as per this writing was in `05/2018`.

You can try running it the other way as described [here](https://coreos.com/rkt/docs/latest/using-rkt-with-kubernetes.html) or [here](https://www.devtech101.com/2017/11/02/configuring-kubernetes-3-node-cluster-coreos-kubelet-rkt-cni-part-4/). Basically, use `--container-runtime=rkt`, `--rkt-path=PATH_TO_RKT_BINARY`, etc. on the kubelet.

Is there a reason why you are need `rkt`? Note that `--container-runtime=rkt` is [deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) in the latest Kubernetes but should still work (1.13 as of this writing).

Comment: I tried this also, Some errors are showing with final message as "rktnetes is deprecated use rktletes instead." That's how I got into rktlet

Comment: Open a github issue on rktlet but not sure you will get a quick response. Is there any reason why you want to use rkt?

Comment: I found docker takes about 450ms to start a container, but rkt is only taking 250 ms. I am checking ways to improve kubernetes deployment performance, which is taking about 1 sec in default configuration for starting a container.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService` but `unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.ImageService` in my case helps to remove "cri" from disabled_plugins in `/etc/containerd/config.toml` config:

```
#disabled_plugins = ["cri"]
disabled_plugins = []
```

and restart containerd service `systemctl restart containerd.service`

Answer (score 0):

You can check `ctr plugin ls` output for some plugin in `error` state:

```
ctr plugin ls
TYPE                            ID                       PLATFORMS      STATUS
io.containerd.content.v1        content                  -              ok
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    aufs                     linux/amd64    skip
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    btrfs                    linux/amd64    skip
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    devmapper                linux/amd64    error
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    native                   linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    overlayfs                linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.snapshotter.v1    zfs                      linux/amd64    skip
io.containerd.metadata.v1       bolt                     -              ok
io.containerd.differ.v1         walking                  linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.gc.v1             scheduler                -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        introspection-service    -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        containers-service       -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        content-service          -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        diff-service             -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        images-service           -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        leases-service           -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        namespaces-service       -              ok
io.containerd.service.v1        snapshots-service        -              ok
io.containerd.runtime.v1        linux                    linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.runtime.v2        task                     linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.monitor.v1        cgroups                  linux/amd64    ok
io.containerd.service.v1        tasks-service            -              ok
io.containerd.internal.v1       restart                  -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           containers               -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           content                  -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           diff                     -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           events                   -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           healthcheck              -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           images                   -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           leases                   -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           namespaces               -              ok
io.containerd.internal.v1       opt                      -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           snapshots                -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           tasks                    -              ok
io.containerd.grpc.v1           version                  -              ok
```